# Erro em variavel JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho o Seguinte código javascript abaixo que ocorre o seguinte erro

> Uncaught ReferenceError: rdIdem is not defined at HTMLInputElement  (ff_admin.php?folder=pedidos/&file=ff_fmins_pedidos&ext=php:806) at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.js:4435) at HTMLDocument.r.handle (jquery.js:4121).

Onde o mesmo é chamado num input type radio. Vocês podem me adjudar a resolver esse erro? **Código completo de toda a pagina a seguir seguir, (lembrando que a função que esta acontecendo o erro é "rdDesIdemRem"):**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).on("change","input[type=radio]",function(){
    var rdRetirar = $('[name="rdRetirar"]:checked').val();

    if(rdRetirar=='sim'){
      $('#rdDestinaIdemRemeS').prop("disabled", true);

      $('#rdDestinaIdemRemeN').prop("disabled", true);

      $('#seldestinatario').prop("disabled", true);
      $('#txtemaild').prop("disabled", true);
      $('#telefone1d').prop("disabled", true);
      $('#telefone2d').prop("disabled", true);
      $('#selEstadod').prop("disabled", true);
      $('#selCidaded').prop("disabled", true);
      $('#selBairrod').prop("disabled", true);
      $('#logradourod').prop("disabled", true);
      $('#numerod').prop("disabled", true);
      $('#complementod').prop("disabled", true);
      //Desabilita os campos de relacionados a terceirizada
      $('#selTerceirizada').prop("disabled", true);
      $('#selVeiculo').prop("disabled", true);
      $('#txtvalortaxa').prop("disabled", true);
      $('#txtvalortaxa').val("0,00");
    }else{
      //Reabilita os campos do destinatario
      $('#rdDestinaIdemRemeS').prop("disabled", false);

      $('#rdDestinaIdemRemeN').prop("disabled", false);

      $('#seldestinatario').prop("disabled", false);
      $('#txtemaild').prop("disabled", false);
      $('#telefone1d').prop("disabled", false);
      $('#telefone1d').prop("required", true);
      $('#telefone2d').prop("disabled", false);
      $('#selEstadod').prop("disabled", false);
      $('#selCidaded').prop("disabled", false);
      $('#selBairrod').prop("disabled", false);
      $('#logradourod').prop("disabled", false);
      $('#numerod').prop("disabled", false);
      $('#complementod').prop("disabled", false);
      //Reabilita os campos de relacionados a terceirizada
      $('#selTerceirizada').prop("disabled", false);
      $('#selVeiculo').prop("disabled", false);
      $('#txtvalortaxa').prop("disabled", false);
      if(rdIdem=="nao"){
        $('#seldestinatario').prop("required", true);
        $('#selEstadod').prop("required", true);
        $('#selCidaded').prop("required", true);
        $('#selBairrod').prop("required", true);
      }
    }


  });


</script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <h1 class="page-header">Registro de Pedidos</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Erro:</span>
    Os campos identificados com  *  são obrigatórios!
  <br>
</div>
<form name="frmpedidos" data-toggle="validator" method="POST" action="?folder=pedidos/&file=ff_ins_pedidos&ext=php" role="form" onsubmit="return validaDetalhe()">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-lg-2 form-control-label">*Data:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10 ">
              <input type="text" name="txtdata" class="form-control datas_pedidos" placeholder="dd-mm-aaaa" required  id="datepicker">
              <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-lg-2 form-control-label">*Horário:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
              <!-- <input type="time" name="txthorario" class="form-control datas_pedidos" placeholder="dd-mm-aaaa" required> -->
              <select class="form-control select-basic" type="text"  name="txthorario" required >
                <option value="">Selecione...</option>
                <option value="01:00 - 02:00">01:00 - 02:00</option>
                <option value="02:00 - 03:00">02:00 - 03:00</option>
                <option value="03:00 - 04:00">03:00 - 04:00</option>
                <option value="04:00 - 05:00">04:00 - 05:00</option>
                <option value="05:00 - 06:00">05:00 - 06:00</option>
                <option value="06:00 - 07:00">06:00 - 07:00</option>
                <option value="07:00 - 08:00">07:00 - 08:00</option>
                <option value="08:00 - 09:00">08:00 - 09:00</option>
                <option value="09:00 - 10:00">09:00 - 10:00</option>
                <option value="10:00 - 11:00">10:00 - 11:00</option>
                <option value="11:00 - 12:00">11:00 - 12:00</option>
                <option value="12:00 - 13:00">12:00 - 13:00</option>
                <option value="13:00 - 14:00">13:00 - 14:00</option>
                <option value="14:00 - 15:00">14:00 - 15:00</option>
                <option value="15:00 - 16:00">15:00 - 16:00</option>
                <option value="16:00 - 17:00">16:00 - 17:00</option>
                <option value="17:00 - 18:00">17:00 - 18:00</option>
                <option value="18:00 - 19:00">18:00 - 19:00</option>
                <option value="19:00 - 20:00">19:00 - 20:00</option>
                <option value="20:00 - 21:00">20:00 - 21:00</option>
                <option value="21:00 - 22:00">21:00 - 22:00</option>
                <option value="22:00 - 23:00">22:00 - 23:00</option>
                <option value="23:00 - 24:00">23:00 - 00:00</option>
                <option value="00:00 - 01:00">00:00 - 01:00</option>
              </select>
              <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12" >
          <div class="form-group row col-lg-12" >
              <label>*Deseja Retirar na Loja? (Isento de Taxas de Entrega)</label>
              <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="rdRetirar" id="rdRetirar" value="nao"  required> NÃO
              </label>
              <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="rdRetirar" id="rdRetirar" value="sim"  onload="RetirarLoja()"> SIM
              </label>
              <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

      <hr class="hr">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  Remetente
                </h4>
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                  <li class="fa fa-minus-square fa-2x navbar-right minimizar"  alt="" width="30px" height="30px"></li>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label class="col-sm-4 form-control-label">*Nome:</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <select name="selremetente" id="selremetente" class="select-tag form-control" maxlenght="45" style="width: 100%;" onChange="buscaremetente()" required>
                          <option value="">Escolha um cliente...</option>
                          <?php
                            $sql_sel_clientes_preparado->execute();

                            while($sql_sel_clientes_dados = $sql_sel_clientes_preparado->fetch()){
                          ?>
                          <option value="<?php echo $sql_sel_clientes_dados['id'];?>"><?php  echo $sql_sel_clientes_dados['nome'];?></option>
                          <?php
                            }
                          ?>
                        </select>
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label class="col-sm-4 form-control-label">E-mail:</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type="email" id="txtemail" name="txtemail" class="form-control" maxlength="70" placeholder="maria@dominio.com.br">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label class="col-sm-4 form-control-label">*Telefone Fixo:</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type="tel" name="txttelefone1" id="telefone1" class="form-control" maxlength="20" placeholder="34391090" pattern="^([0-9]{1,20})$" required>
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label class="col-sm-4 form-control-label">Telefone Celular:</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type="tel" name="txttelefone2" id="telefone2" class="form-control" maxlength="20" pattern="^([0-9]{1,20})$" placeholder="99445218123">
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label class="col-sm-4 form-control-label">Estado:</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <select name="selestado" id="selEstado" class="select-basic form-control" style="width: 100%;" onChange="mostrarcidade()">
                          <option value="">Escolha um Estado..</option>
                          <?php
                            $sql_sel_estados_preparado->execute();

                            while($sql_sel_estados_dados = $sql_sel_estados_preparado->fetch()){
                          ?>
                          <option value="<?php echo $sql_sel_estados_dados['id'];?>"><?php  echo $sql_sel_estados_dados['nome'];?></option>
                          <?php
                            }
                          ?>
                        </select>
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label class="col-sm-4 form-control-label">Cidade:</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <select name="selcidade" id="selCidade" class="select-basic form-control" style="width: 100%;" onchange="mostrarbairro()">
                          <option value=''>Escolha um Estado Primeiro...</option>
                        </select>
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label class="col-sm-4 form-control-label">Bairro:</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <select name="selbairro" id="selBairro" class="select-basic form-control" style="width: 100%;">
                          <option value=''>Escolha uma Cidade Primeiro...</option>
                        </select>
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label class="col-sm-4 form-control-label">Logradouro:</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type="text" id="txtlogradouro" name="txtlogradouro" class="form-control" placeholder="Marques de Olinda" maxlength="45">
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label class="col-sm-4 form-control-label">Número:</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type="text" id="txtnumero" name="txtnumero" class="form-control" maxlength="6" placeholder="1222">
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label class="col-sm-4 form-control-label">CPF:</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type="text" id="cpf" name="txtcpf" class="form-control" maxlength="11" pattern="^[0-9]{3}[0-9]{3}[0-9]{3}[0-9]{2}$" placeholder="01234567890">
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!--/. div col-md-12 col-lg-6  -->
                  <div class="form-group row col-lg-12">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 form-control-label" >Comentário / Complemento:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <textarea type"text" name="txtacomplemento" id="complemento" class="form-control" placeholder="Comentário/Complemento do endereço do Remetente..."></textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
          <!-- /.panel-collapse collapse in -->
          <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  Destinatário
                </h4>
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
                <li class="fa fa-minus-square fa-2x navbar-right minimizar"  alt="" width="30px" height="30px"></li>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                      function rdDesIdemRem(){
                        var rdIdem = $('[name="rdDestinaIdemReme"]:checked').val();
                        if(rdIdem=="sim"){

                           var selremetente = $('#selremetente').val();
                           $('#seldestinatario').val(selremetente);
                           $('#seldestinatario').prop("required", false);
                           var txtemail = $('#txtemail').val();
                           $('#txtemaild').val(txtemail);
                           var telefone1 = $('#telefone1').val();
                           $('#telefone1d').val(telefone1);
                           var telefone2 = $('#telefone2').val();
                           $('#telefone2d').val(telefone2);
                           var selEstado = $('#selEstado').val();
                           $('#selEstadod').val(selEstado);
                           $('#selEstadod').prop("required", false);
                           var selCidade = $('#selCidade').val();
                           $('#selCidaded').val(selCidade);
                           $('#selCidaded').prop("required", false);
                           var selBairro = $('#selBairro').val();
                           $('#selBairrod').val(selBairro);
                           $('#selBairrod').prop("required", false);
                           var logradouro = $('#txtlogradouro').val();
                           $('#logradourod').val(logradouro);
                           var numero = $('#txtnumero').val();
                           $('#numerod').val(numero);
                           var complemento = $('#complemento').val();
                           $('#complementod').val(complemento);

                           if(selEstado==""){
                             alert("Favor preencher o campo Estado na seção do Remetente!");
                             $("#rdDestinaIdemRemeN").prop("checked", true);
                           }else if(selCidade==""){
                             alert("Favor preencher o campo Cidade na seção do Remetente!");
                             $("#rdDestinaIdemRemeN").prop("checked", true);
                             }else if(selBairro==""){
                               alert("Favor preencher o campo Bairro na seção do Remetente!");
                               $("#rdDestinaIdemRemeN").prop("checked", true);
                               }else if((logradouro=="") && (complemento=="")){
                                 alert("Favor preencher o campo Logradouro ou Complemento na seção do Remetente!");
                                 $("#rdDestinaIdemRemeN").prop("checked", true);
                                 }else if((numero=="") &&(complemento=="")){
                                   alert("Favor preencher o campo Número ou Complemento na seção do Remetente!");
                                   $("#rdDestinaIdemRemeN").prop("checked", true);
                                 }


                        }else{
                          $('#seldestinatario').val("");
                          $('#txtemaild').val("");
                          $('#telefone1d').val("");
                          $('#telefone2d').val("");
                          $('#selEstadod').val("");
                          $('#selCidaded').val("");
                          $('#selBairrod').val("");
                          $('#logradourod').val("");
                          $('#numerod').val("");
                          $('#complementod').val("");
                        }
                      }
                    </script>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label class="col-sm-5 form-control-label">* O Destinatário é o mesmo que o Remetente?:</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-7">
                        <input type="radio" name="rdDestinaIdemReme" id="rdDestinaIdemRemeS" value="sim"  required onClick="rdDesIdemRem()"> SIM ou
                        <input type="radio" name="rdDestinaIdemReme" id="rdDestinaIdemRemeN"  value="nao"  onClick="rdDesIdemRem()" checked> NÃO
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-12" id="DivdoDestinatario">
                  <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label class="col-sm-4 form-control-label">*Nome:</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <select name="seldestinatario" id="seldestinatario" class="select-tag form-control" maxlenght="45" style="width: 100%;" onChange="buscadestinatario()" >
                          <option value="">Escolha um Destinatario...</option>
                          <?php
                            $sql_sel_clientes_preparado->execute();
                            while($sql_sel_clientes_dados = $sql_sel_clientes_preparado->fetch()){
                          ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $sql_sel_clientes_dados['id'];?>"><?php  echo $sql_sel_clientes_dados['nome'];?></option>
                          <?php
                            }
                          ?>
                        </select>
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label class="col-sm-4 form-control-label">E-mail:</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type="email" id="txtemaild" name="txtemaild" class="form-control" maxlength="70"  placeholder="Joao@dominio.com.br">
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>

                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label class="col-sm-4 form-control-label">*Telefone Fixo:</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type="tel" name="txttelefone1d" id="telefone1d" class="form-control" pattern="^([0-9]{1,20})$" maxlength="20" placeholder="34391090" >
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label class="col-sm-4 form-control-label">Telefone Celular:</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type="tel" name="txttelefone2d" id="telefone2d" class="form-control" maxlength="20" pattern="^([0-9]{1,20})$" placeholder="955123231351">
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label class="col-sm-4 form-control-label">*Estado:</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <select name="selestadod" id="selEstadod" class="select-basic form-control" style="width: 100%;" onChange="mostrarcidaded()" >
                          <option value="">Escolha um Estado..</option>
                          <?php
                            $sql_sel_estados_preparado->execute();
                            while($sql_sel_estados_dados = $sql_sel_estados_preparado->fetch()){
                          ?>
                          <option value="<?php echo $sql_sel_estados_dados['id'];?>"><?php  echo $sql_sel_estados_dados['nome'];?></option>
                          <?php
                            }
                          ?>
                        </select>
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label class="col-sm-4 form-control-label">*Cidade:</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <select name="selcidaded" id="selCidaded" class="select-basic form-control" style="width: 100%;" onchange="mostrarbairrod()" >
                          <option value=''>Escolha um Estado Primeiro...</option>
                        </select>
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label class="col-sm-4 form-control-label">*Bairro:</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <select name="selbairrod" id="selBairrod" class="select-basic form-control" style="width: 100%;" >
                          <option value=''>Escolha uma Cidade Primeiro...</option>
                        </select>
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label class="col-sm-4 form-control-label">*Logradouro:</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type="text" name="txtlogradourod" id="logradourod" class="form-control" placeholder="Marques de Olinda" maxlength="45">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label class="col-sm-4 form-control-label">*Número:</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type="text" name="txtnumerod" id="numerod" class="form-control" maxlength="6" placeholder="1222" onclick="descricaoDestinoObrg()">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!--/. div col-md-12 col-lg-6  -->
                  <div class="form-group row col-lg-12">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Comentário / Complemento:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <textarea type"text" name="txtacomplementod" id="complementod" class="form-control" placeholder="Comentário/Complemento do endereço do Destinatário..." ></textarea>
                      <div class="help-block with-errors" style="color: rgb(217, 65, 65);">Necessário caso logradouro e número não estejam preenchidos!</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Ele está dizendo que `$('[name="rdDestinaIdemReme"]:checked').val();` não foi encontrado na página

Comment: Sim só que esta na pagina inclusive a função chega a funcionar e fazer oq tem que fazer, que no caso é copiar os dados de outros inputs que já foram preenchidos

Comment: Então o código funciona? Cara não estou entendendo

Comment: Sim o código funciona só que da como a variável indefinida

Comment: A unica coisa que pode ser é que ele não está encontrando este radio, você já olhou neste arquivo `ff_admin.php` na linha 806?

Comment: sim , nada de errado, :c, dei uma olhada em outros sites, e falava que era alguma coisa relacionada com variável global, mas não consegui resolver!

Comment: Fica um pouco difícil resolver sem o código completo :/ esse é um tipo de problema que realmente precisa ser estudado como um todo

Comment: vou postar a pagina inteira então

Answer (score 1, accepted):

você está tentando acessar uma variável que não existe no seu escopo atual.

você está à declarar `rdIdem` dentro de `function rdDesIdemRem()`, por tanto ela só é acessível dentro desta função.

ao tentar acessar a mesma dentro do evento `change` do `input[type=radio]` á mesma não esta disponível, então o seu valor é nulo.

então a solução para o seu problema, é declarar ela novamente dentro do escopo do `change`

```
$(document).on("change","input[type=radio]",function(){
  var rdRetirar = $('[name="rdRetirar"]:checked').val();
  var rdIdem = $('[name="rdDestinaIdemReme"]:checked').val();
  // restante do codigo aqui.
}
```

Comment: Então, realmente funcionou e parou de bugar! Obrigado